# How to fetch an ID from the table using replace,substring charindex in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables (`#temp1` and `#temp2`) as shown in the below code and I'm trying to get the matching static ID for the values present in `#temp2` table but there is problem with the below code such that it returns null `staticID` value.

I'm not sure where its getting wrong can someone let me know whats the mistake I'm doing in the below code ?

```
 BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #temp2
      (
         staticname VARCHAR(160),
      )

    INSERT INTO #temp2
    VALUES      ('Per capita disappearance, carcass weight(456)'),
                ('Production(286)')

    CREATE TABLE #temp1
      (
         idnum         INTEGER IDENTITY(1, 1),
         statisticname VARCHAR(256),
         staticid      INTEGER
      )

    INSERT INTO #temp1
    VALUES      ('Per capita disappearance, carcass weight',
                 '144'),
                ('Production',
                 '143')

SELECT 
    Ltrim (Rtrim (Replace (T2.staticname, Substring(T2.staticname,
                  Charindex('(', T2.staticname, 0),
                  Len(T2.staticname) - ( Charindex('(', T2.staticname, 0) - 1 )), ''
       ))),
    T1.staticid
FROM   
    #temp2 T2
LEFT JOIN 
    #temp1 T1 ON T2.staticname = T1.statisticname

DROP TABLE #temp1
DROP TABLE #temp2
```

Comment: You should be using in memory tables for this. Temp2 table should be split up as separate fields like Temp1.

Comment: Your join criteria is not going to find a match there. You would do yourself some big favors by not making everything all upper case. It is so hard to read. And you really should not be putting multiple values into a single column like this. It is a real pain to work with.

Comment: This is just an example of a part in the code where it's not working... Problem is the #temp2 values has name(some number) in it.. I need to remove the number part and fetch the ID for the matching names.... Does the above problem have solution?

Comment: using LIKE operator can solve the problem. Check my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#temp1` table's `STATISTICNAME` values

```
Per capita disappearance, carcass weight
Production
```

are not matching with `#temp2` table's `STATISTICNAME` values

```
Per capita disappearance, carcass weight(456)
Production(286)
```

Since using the `LEFT JOIN` so obviously the left table `#temp` data will come, so the `STATICID` column from `#temp1` is returning `NULL`

If you want to do the partial search with the columns use the `LIKE` operator. So your `LEFT JOIN` block will be:

```
LEFT JOIN #TEMP1 T1 ON T2.STATICNAME LIKE T1.STATISTICNAME + '%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the columns that match in the `JOIN`

```
SELECT LTRIM (RTRIM (REPLACE (T2.STATICNAME,SUBSTRING(T2.STATICNAME, CHARINDEX('(',T2.STATICNAME,0), LEN(T2.STATICNAME)-(CHARINDEX('(',T2.STATICNAME,0)-1)),    '')))
       ,T1.STATICID
FROM #TEMP2 T2 LEFT JOIN #TEMP1 T1 ON LTRIM (RTRIM (REPLACE (T2.STATICNAME,SUBSTRING(T2.STATICNAME, CHARINDEX('(',T2.STATICNAME,0), LEN(T2.STATICNAME)-(CHARINDEX('(',T2.STATICNAME,0)-1)),    ''))) 
                                      = T1.STATISTICNAME
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not joining on the parsed value.  Try this:

```
 BEGIN

CREATE TABLE #TEMP2
(
  STATICNAME Varchar(160),
  )

INSERT INTO #TEMP2 VALUES ('Per capita disappearance, carcass weight(456)'),('Production(286)')
  CREATE TABLE #TEMP1
(
IDNUM INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1),
STATISTICNAME VARCHAR(256),
STATICID INTEGER
)

INSERT INTO #TEMP1 VALUES ('Per capita disappearance, carcass weight','144'),('Production','143')

;With cteParsed As
(Select *,
    LTRIM (RTRIM (REPLACE (T2.STATICNAME,SUBSTRING(T2.STATICNAME, 
    CHARINDEX('(',T2.STATICNAME,0), LEN(T2.STATICNAME)-
    (CHARINDEX('(',T2.STATICNAME,0)-1)),    ''))) StaticNameParsed
    From #Temp2 T2
)
Select *, T1.STATICID 
    From cteParsed T2 
    LEFT JOIN #TEMP1 T1 ON T2.StaticNameParsed = T1.STATISTICNAME
DROP TABLE #TEMP1
DROP TABLE #TEMP2
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are looking for, but your join was failing

```
Select A.*,B.*
 From #Temp1 A 
 Join #Temp2 B on ( B.STATICNAME Like A.STATISTICNAME+'%'  )
```